# tag synonyms - how to vote? why is there no change

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonym-process

A month ago I suggested a tag synonym, which to date has no votes or whatever.

[image]

As you can see, there are tag synonyms that are used by multiple questions already, yet they are pending. The `sqlitedatabase` synonym for `sqlite` is apparently used by no question, yet it got approved.

I'm just wondering, who can vote, and if for example I can vote, where can I do that? What's the process behind it? Does it even work, or is it just for moderators?

Please shed some light on this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I go to for example the [reactjs tag synonym page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/reactjs/synonyms) there's a message at the bottom explaining how it works

> Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or
>   more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer
>   score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag,
>   can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved
>   when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they
>   reach a score of -2.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Well, okay, but it seems that hardly anyone ever has a look on it. So I was hoping to get an answer like "yes, we admins check every 3 months" or whatever. Or just raise some attention. Alone some synonyms in the screenshot are from 2012. Thanks for answer though, I upvote and if no other better answer is posted in reasonable time I will accept as well.

Comment: I agree with the notion that it's hard to get people to actually vote for synonyms. I wish there was some kind of visual indicator telling me if there's currently an open vote when I visit a tag. I've seen this subject brought up before and I think the general consensus is that you need to rally support either in chat or in a question here on meta if you want to get anything done about synonyms.

Comment: Maybe this is a dumb idea, but shouldn't there be a Tag Synonym Review Queue? Only showing tags which are available to vote on for the user in question of course.